# No rule to make target in QtCreator compilation on Windows with LLVM

Tags: qt, qt-creator, llvm-clang

I need to compile a cocos2dx project on Windows 10 which has some objective-c++ code, and all that using QtCreator. I've managed to set the compilers in the kit to `LLVM` (so that objective-c++ code can be compiled), as well as change the `qmakespec` to `win32-clang-g++`, however, I'm still getting this error when trying to compile:

```
error: No rule to make target 'C:/Qt/Qt5.12.9/5.12.9/msvc2017_64/lib/libQt5OpenGLd.a', needed by 'debug/libcocos2d.a'.  Stop.
```

The folder in question contains file `Qt5OpenGLd.lib`, but doesn't have `libQt5OpenGLd.a`.

How do I fix this? I can provide more info, but I'm not sure what info is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `win32-clnag-msvc` in order to have it compile a `.lib` file instead of `.a` file.